# NSTimer with UIScrollView paging

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview

I already have a scrollview with an image in and I set paging in the IB to on, so I didn't use a pageControl. That all works, and I can go between images, but how can I make it automatically scroll? Like the thing on the featured page of the App Store?

I was thinking of having two NSTimers - one to scroll 320 points in say 0.3 seconds, and a second to count 4 seconds which then fires the first one. How would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead using of `NSTimer` you can use `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]`

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // start repeatable method
    [self performSelector:@selector(makeTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0f];
}

- (void) makeTick {

    [self performSelector:@selector(makeTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];

    // Calclulate new offset
    CGPoint pt = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    pt.x += self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    // If it's a last subview in scrollview return back
    if (!(pt.x < self.scrollView.contentSize.width)) {
        pt.x = 0;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
}
```

BUT! It's a just simple example how to make you scroll "animated". If you want make "infinitive" scroll behavior like in AppStore you have to use another solution.

Check [this tutorial](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) to make circular and infinitive scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for replying - this automatically scrolled the view, but after a 4 second delay at the start, the rest of the subViews just fly by. So I changed [self performSelector:@selector(makeTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f]; to [self performSelector:@selector(makeTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0f]; and now it works. Thanks so much!